# Find the ratio of male teachers to male students

Tags: arithmetic, ratio

At a school function, the ratio of teachers to students is $5:18$. The ratio of female students to male students is $7:2$. If the ratio of the female teachers to female students is $1:7$, find the ratio of the male teachers to male students.

Comment: What have you tried?  Are there any equations you can create from the information you have?

Answer (score 2):

Let's say that there are $T_f$ female teachers, $T_m$ male teachers, $S_f$ female students, and $S_m$ male students. You are given that,

$$
(T_f + T_m) / (S_f + S_m) = 5/18\\
S_f / S_m = 7/2\\
T_f / S_f = 1/7
$$

And what you want to find is,

$$
T_m / S_m
$$

You can solve this now by substituting in the things you already know,

$$
T_f = 1/7 \times S_f \\
S_m = 2/7 \times S_f \\
T_m = 5/18 \times (S_f + S_m) - T_f
$$

So,

$$
\begin{aligned}
T_m/S_m &= T_m / S_f \times S_f / S_m \\
&= (5/18 \times (S_f + S_m) - T_f) / S_f \times 7/2 \\
&= (5/18 \times (S_f + 2/7 \times S_f) - 1/7 \times S_f) / S_f \times 7/2 \\
&= (5/18 \times (1 + 2/7) - 1/7) \times 7/2 \\
&= 3/4
\end{aligned}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Lets consider there are 7 female student and 2 male student.(7:2)

total student = 9

teacher : student = 5:18

therefore for 18 student there will be 14 girls and 4 boy students

5:14:4

now only 1 female teacher is required for 7 female students (1:7)

here we have 14 female students hence 2 female teacher is required

and total teacher is 5

out of it 2 are female hence 3 teacher are male

5:14:4(teacher:female student:male student)

3:2:14:4(male teacher: female teacher :female student:male student)

hence 3: 4

this is what i found if its wrong please reply

Answer (score 0):

Let A = # of Female Teachers

Let B = # of Male Teachers

Let X = # of Female Students

Let Y = # of Male Students

Then the statement "the ratio of Teachers to students is 5:18" can be represented by the following equation, EQ1:

EQ1: (A+B)/(X+Y) = 5/18 _________(A+B = number of teachers, X+Y = number of students)

```
 18*(A+B) = 5*(X+Y) _________(Still EQ1)

 18*A + 18*B = 5*X + 5*Y ____(Still EQ1)
```

The statement "the ratio of famale students to male students can be represented by the following equation, EQ2:

EQ2:  X/Y = 7/2  -->  X = (7/2)*Y

The statement "the ratio of female teachers to female students can be represented by the following equation, EQ3:

EQ3: A/X = 1/7  -->  A = X/7

We want to solve for the ratio of male teachers (B) to male students (Y)

In order to do that, we want first want to substitute X in EQ3 with the value of X defined in EQ2

A = X/7

A = (7/2)*Y/7 ____________(substituted (7/2)*Y for X)

A = Y/2  ________________ (We will call this EQ4)

Now, we want to substitute X in EQ1 with the value of X defined in EQ2, and A in EQ1 with the value of A defined in EQ4, and solve for B/Y.

18*A + 18*B = 5*X + 5*Y _____________________(EQ1 from above)

18*(Y/2) + 18*B = 5*((7/2)*Y) + 5*Y _________(Substituted for A and X)

9*Y + 18*B = 17.5*Y + 5*Y

18*B = 17.5*Y + 5*Y - 9*Y

18*B = 13.5*Y

B/Y = 13.5/18 = 3/4

Therefore, the ratio of male teachers to male students, B:Y = 3:4.